# Testing Parse on Android

Tags: android, testing, parse-platform

I am trying to write JUnit tests for Parse application on Android. Has anyone done some before? I am using Robolectric but when I try to test any Parse queries (even local) the callback methods are not triggered.

Thanks

Comment: Are these callback methods run on a separate thread? As robolectric unit test is intended to work on single threaded environment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I switched to using Instrumented Unit Test (AndroidJUnit4) and synchronous methods and it all seems to work well. Just to point out - testing the localdatastore was a priority for me so this solution was satisfying.